# Node Express - "req.params.name" is undefined

Tags: node.js, express

In my project which is based on Express and Node, when I visit `http://localhost:3000/users/lbs`, req.params.name" should be equal to 'lbs',but it is undefined.

```
//app.js
app.use("/users/:name",username);

//username.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('user: ' + req.params.name);
});
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you should change it to:

```
//app.js
app.use("/users",username);

//username.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/:name', function(req, res) {
    res.send('user: ' + req.params.name);
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Thank you. Your method is effective.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution :

```
//app.js
app.use("/users",username);

//username.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/:name', function(req, res) {
    res.send('user: ' + req.param('name'));
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: We should use `req.params.name` to get the value. `req.param('name')` is also undefined.